# Header Issue with S3 PUT Command

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, dropzone.js

I'm trying to do a server-less upload to S3 using [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). I'm having issues with the AWS Presigned URL specifically, where it's indicating that the `x-amz-acl` header is unsigned.

Javascript:

```
var dz = new Dropzone("div#upload", {
  url: "tbd",
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: this.getUploadUrl,
  method: 'put',
  sending: function(file, xhr) {
    var _send = xhr.send;
      xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
      xhr.send = function() {
        _send.call(xhr, file);
      }
    },
});

dz.on('processing', function(file) {
  // change url before sending
  this.options.url = file.uploadUrl;
});

function getUploadUrl(file, cb) {
  var params = {
    fileName: file.name,
    fileType: file.type,
  };
  $.getJSON('signput.php', params).done(function(data) {
    var decodedUri = decodeURIComponent(data['signedRequest']);
    if (!data.signedRequest) {
      return cb('Failed to receive an upload url');
    }

    console.log(decodedUri);
    file.uploadUrl = decodedUri;
    cb();
  }).fail(function() {
    return cb('Failed to receive an upload url');
  });
}
```

PHP (called to get presigned url):

```
$fileName = $_GET['fileName'];

$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'version'     => '2006-03-01',
'region'      => 'us-west-2',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => '__MY__KEY__',
    'secret' => '__MY__SECRET__',
],]);

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => '__MY__BUCKET__',
    'Key'    => $fileName
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$url = (string) $request->getUri();

$urlArray['signedRequest'] = $url;
$urlArray = json_encode($urlArray);
echo $urlArray;
```

I've also tried setting `x-amz-acl` to public-read in the Dropzone headers and S3 getCommand, but it's not working.

The error I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message>
<HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-acl</HeadersNotSigned>
</Error>
```

Comment: Try `$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => '__MY__BUCKET__',
    'Key'    => $fileName, 'ACL' => 'public-read'
]);`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No luck :(

Comment: I tried ACL, AMZ-ACL, and X-AMZ-ACL also

Comment: Be more specific?

Comment: Getting the same error, that there are unsigned headers - no change in the error message

Comment: `'ACL'` is definitely the way to pass it to the request builder https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject but the header name should still be `x-amz-acl`.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction - the JS code was overwriting the ACL (if you look in the sending function). It works, thank you!

Comment: Excellent.  Your answer looks good.  When I first started using AWS, several years ago, I started without any SDK and wrote all my own.  I believe this was an advantage, because I believe that generally the SDKs -- presumably in an attempt to simplify things -- hide too much from the user.  Adding `'ACL' => ...` to the signing request implicitly adds `x-amz-acl:...` to the headers that contribute to the final signature, on the assumption that you would also, separately, add that header to your final request... but how exactly you would know to put these two together seems to be left unstated.

Comment: Yeah it would definitely help make things more clear - your link helped me narrow it down so thanks again, I'll be using it in the future! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was one issue - I needed to move the `ACL => 'public-read'` from the JS code into the signing request.

The Dropzone sending function turns into this:

```
sending: function(file, xhr) {
    var _send = xhr.send;
    xhr.send = function() {
      _send.call(xhr, file);
    }
  }
```

And the PHP signing requests turns into:

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
  'Bucket' => '__MY__BUCKET__',
  'Key'    => $fileName,
  'ACL'   => 'public-read'
]);
```

Thanks to Michael for pointing me in the right direction.

Final code for reference...

Javascript:

```
var dz = new Dropzone("div#upload", {
  url: "tbd",
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: this.getUploadUrl,
  method: 'put',
  sending: function(file, xhr) {
      var _send = xhr.send;
      xhr.send = function() {
        _send.call(xhr, file);
      }
    },
});

dz.on('processing', function(file) {
  // change url before sending
  this.options.url = file.uploadUrl;
});

function getUploadUrl(file, cb) {
  var params = {
    fileName: file.name,
    fileType: file.type,
  };
  $.getJSON('signput.php', params).done(function(data) {
    var decodedUri = decodeURIComponent(data['signedRequest']);
    if (!data.signedRequest) {
      return cb('Failed to receive an upload url');
    }

    file.uploadUrl = decodedUri;
    cb();
  }).fail(function() {
    return cb('Failed to receive an upload url');
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
$fileName = $_GET['fileName'];

$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'version'     => '2006-03-01',
'region'      => 'us-west-2',
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => '__MY_KEY__',
    'secret' => '__MY_SECRET__,
],]);


$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
  'Bucket' => '__MY_BUCKET__',
  'Key'    => $fileName,
  'ACL'   => 'public-read'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$url = (string) $request->getUri();

$urlArray['signedRequest'] = $url;
$urlArray = json_encode($urlArray);
echo $urlArray;
```